# The provability predicate in Peano Arithmetic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, incompleteness

I am aware of the fact, that the following considerations can be done for various strong enough theories in various first-order languages. I am, however, only interested (for simplicity) in the case for first-order Peano arithmetic.

In the development done before proving Gödel's second incompleteness theorem in most textbooks, one constructs the proof predicate $\mathrm{Proof}(x,y)$ such that

$$\mathsf{PA}\vdash\phi\text{ iff there is an $m\in\mathbb N$ such that }\mathsf{PA}\vdash\mathrm{Proof}(n,m)\text{ where $n$ is the Gödel number of $\phi$}$$

where, with $\mathrm{Proof}(n,m)$, I mean to substitute the terms representing $n,m$ for $x,y$ in $\mathrm{Proof}$.

One may proceed to derive the provability predicate $\mathrm{Prf}$ from this by existentially quantifying the variable $y$ in $\mathrm{Proof}$ and to prove the Löb derivability conditions for this predicate, which then leads to the second incompleteness theorem.

What I am wondering about is the following: The approach to the first incompleteness theorem that I am most used to is to show that

$$\{n\in\mathbb N\mid n\text{ is the Gödel number of some $\phi$ such that }\mathsf{PA}\vdash\phi\}=T$$

is not representable in $\mathsf{PA}$, i.e. that there is no formula $\mathrm{R}(x)$ with one free variable $x$ in the language of arithmetic such that

1. If $n\in T$, then $\mathsf{PA}\vdash R(n)$.
2. If $n\not\in T$, then $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\neg R(n)$.

That means that the proof predicate $\mathrm{Prf}$ can not be a representation of the set $T$. Does this make the provability predicate `less` of a proper provability predicate? I would just like to put these things in order in my head.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Less than what? Less in what sense?

Comment: To be clear here, they are using represent to mean "present a formula which is always provable or disprovable", not represent in the colloquial sense of "present a formula that means what we want to define".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the facts you’ve laid out show is that PA cannot prove/refute every instance of the provability predicate. This should come as no surprise since the second incompleteness theorem says that it cannot refute *any* negative instance, much less every. So it is really PA that is failing here, not the predicate.

I think your error is going from “does not represent in PA” to “cannot be a representation of”. The former is a technical concept, whereas the latter, stripped of the crucial qualifier “in PA”, sounds a lot stronger than what the former actually means. For instance, the provablility predicate definitely defines $T$ in $\mathbb N,$ in the usual sense that it is true of $n$ if and only if $n\in T.$